# tangent vectors defined by smooth curves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

I would like to know under which (minimal) conditions an irreducible complex algebraic variety $X$ has the following property: given a closed point $P\in X$, the tangent space $T_PX$ of $X$ at $P$ is generated by the tangent lines defined by smooth curves in $X$ through $P$.

($T_PX$ is defined as the dual of the vector space $m_P/m_P^2$, where $m_P$ is the maximal ideal of ${\mathcal O}_{X,P}$)

Comment: If you're happy with proving the result only for a *general* point $p$, then quasi-projective and regular in codimension $1$ is enough. The idea is to use a Bertini type theorem to cut by hyperplanes until we reach dimension $1$. The point is that a general hypersurface $H \subseteq X$ has $H^{\operatorname{sing}} \subsetneq X^{\operatorname{sing}}$, i.e. $H$ is smooth where $X$ is, and cuts down the singular locus. Then the curve we get in the end is smooth. However, we can only guarantee existence of such a hypersurface through a general point $p \in X$, not through an arbitrary point.

Comment: My assumption is already enough to reduce to the case $\dim X=2$, using a slightly different version of the argument in my previous comment. Indeed, apply the Bertini theorem as in Hartshorne, **Theorem III.10.9** to $X\setminus(\{p\}\cup X^{\operatorname{sing}})$ for the linear system of hypersurfaces through $p$. We conclude that a general $H$ through $p$ only has singularities along $\{p\}\cup X^{\operatorname{sing}}$. Moreover, a general $H$ does not contain $X^{\operatorname{sing}}$, so it cuts down the singular locus. As long as $\dim H\geq 2$, $H$ is still regular in codimension $1$.

Comment: You also have to use that the tangent spaces of general $H$ at $p$ together span the tangent space of $X$ at $p$, so that the result for $H$ implies the result for $X$. The reason I posted my second comment is to convince you to think about the surface case first; the general case is not necessarily much harder.

Comment: Finally, a question for the OP: do you require your curves to be closed in $X$? If not, there might be easier approaches than the one I gave in my comments (because you only have to worry about it being smooth at $p$; any other singularities you can just remove by taking an open subset of the curve).

Comment: @R. van Dobben de Bruyn Thank you for your comments. The curves have not to be closed in $X$. But I must assume that $X$ is reduced. The case of smooth points of $X$ is then trivial. We have only to treat the singular points of $X$.